# Google maps draw artifacts

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

While developing my current project i'm using Google maps. I draw some circles on map and i figured out some artifacts on map after scaling or moving map. But let's have a look to official Google Maps Circles demo from documentation: [Google Maps Circles Simple](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/circle-simple?hl=ru)

In this demo i have this bugs as well. Here is some screenshots of bugs:

[image: http://image.prntscr.com/image/7f4681b520ec43bb9abb6035c0c2b346.png]
[image]

Some facts i have figured out:

1. Bugs appears only in Google Chrome browser (In other browsers everything is ok);
2. Bugs appears only in my company's office (i have tried at home, my friends tried from another locations, PCs, they have everything ok)

Comment: try clear the browser cache

Comment: I've tried browser cache, turn off network, it didn't help.

Comment: Yes happened only in google chrome 58 versions. Hope its a browser related bug.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something fishy is happening in Chrome 58. Take a look at this bug report in the issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38211242

The behavior is similar to yours. Feel free to add your comments in the public issue and star it. Specify you browser and OS version, which extensions you use in Chrome etc. This can help to reproduce the issue by Google team.

**UPDATE**

As stated in Google issue tracker, the issue was fixed in Chrome 60. The corresponding bug was marked as Fixed on August 9, 2017.

Comment: We expected when we turn off `hardware acceleration` bug disappear http://image.prntscr.com/image/d65b6c9ba523451b8c587243fb622e79.png Thanks for your response. I will post all information i have to issue tracker and hope it will help Google team.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated to Chrome version 59.0.3071.109 (Official Build) (64-bit) available today. It appears to have fixed this issue.

Open Settings, click About, and update to 59.