# Error at rendering circles - Google Maps Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm developing a web app which has a map and where the user can set circles wherever he wants. Then he can see every circle he has set.

But when I load the circles that the user has, this happens: 
[image: Oops!]

The user that I´m using to test has 5 circles, the ones that appear complete. The rest is junk that just appears there and I´m not sure why.

This is my code (I´m using RoR):

Javascript:

```
function initMap() {

  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: pos,
          map: map,
          icon: "<%= asset_path('marker.png') %>"
        });

      map.setCenter(pos);

    }, function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
}

function loadUserTargets() {
  $.getJSON('/circles/list', function(circlesList) {
    if(circlesList.length > 0) {
      jQuery.each(circlesList, function(index, circle){
        var circleCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(circle.latitude, circle.longitude);
        drawCircleAt(circleCenter, circle.radius);
      });
    }
  });
}

function drawCircleAt(location, radius) {

  return new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillColor: '#efc537',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    map: map,
    center: location,
    radius: radius
  });
}
```

When I call getJSON('/circles/list', ...) I get the following in return:

```
[{"id":4,"latitude":-34.9001517737747,"longitude":-56.1877727508545,"radius":456},
{"id":5,"latitude":-34.8983567053717,"longitude":-56.1922359466553,"radius":367},
{"id":6,"latitude":-34.9032138587385,"longitude":-56.1949396133423,"radius":100},
{"id":7,"latitude":-34.9053255749513,"longitude":-56.2041234970093,"radius":200},
{"id":8,"latitude":-34.9103230869756,"longitude":-56.18408203125,"radius":500}]
```

Does anybody know what´s going on?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This bug was handled in the isssue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38211242.
It was fixed in August 2017.

Comment: Where are you calling `loadUserTargets` and can you give an example of what `getJSON('/circles/list'` returns?

Comment: Done @GabeRogan, and loadUserTargets is called in the $(document).ready() function

Comment: Have a look at my answer in the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43937197/5140781

Comment: Hm very peculiar behavior indeed. From your other question it definitely sounds like a bug. I would help, but I think Google is much better suited to handle this :)

Comment: Yes, I don´t think my code is the problem, I went over it several times, but it´s also hard to believe that the Javascript Google Maps API has such a strange behavior. Thanks anyways @GabeRogan

Comment: I might have found the answer to this problem. Chrome has an option in its settings that says 'Use hardware acceleration when available'. I switched that off and for now it´s working. I'll write a proper solution in this article in a few days if I don´t see the initial behavior again. @GabeRogan

Comment: As stated in Google issue tracker, the issue was fixed in Chrome 60. The corresponding bug was marked as Fixed on August 9, 2017.